# Create a RSS feed of file attachments to a particular node

Tags: 7, views, feeds

I am looking to create a RSS feed of file attachments, filtered by the node they are attached to.

for instance the feed URL would be:

```
node/253/rss-attachments.xml
```

where `253` is the node ID in question. Using views 3 + drupal 7 I am able use 'files' as a base table, and create a list of files with a contextual filter of node ID, however upon adding the RSS display it complains saying:

> Style RSS Feed requires a row style but the row plugin is invalid.

I have the feeling that a custom row style plugin is required here. Does anyone have any ideas as to what options exist now for solving this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Views RSS](http://drupal.org/project/views_rss) module for creating complex feeds with Drupal Fields. The module provides a lot of RSS settings:

[image]

1. RSS format plugin “RSS Feed - Fields” with settings
2. Support for core fields.
3. Enclosure elements

The result can look like this:
[image]